# Running executable from a Perl-Linux based website on Windows?

Tags: html, perl, onclick, executable

I have the following situation: a Linux server hosting a website created by a Perl code.
I have created with Perl a button that onclick should start an executable.
Problem is the executable is a Windows EXE file. When button clicked it is run on the Linux server and not the Windows side.
How do I change the "onclick" to start the EXE (when website is opened in Windows)?

Code for onclick:

```
onclick="javascript: runExe();"
```

Tried the following:

```
    function runExe (){
    system("/Users/xxxx/notepad.exe");
}

    function runExe (){
    system("file://C:/Windows/notepad.exe");
}

    function runExe (){
    open(FH, "c:\Windows\notepad.exe |");
    close(FH);
    }

    function runExe (){
        open(FH, "/Users/xxxx/notepad.exe |");
        close(FH);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, you can't, host your Perlsite on a Windows server if you need to run windows executables. Long answer, you could try to use [wine](http://www.winehq.org/) to run the program under linux. Depending on the exe in question, this may not work well.

Comment: Thanks! You gave me an idea. I can open an html page from ANOTHER Windows server (with IIS) and go from there. Thanks!